# How to run .exe file in specific location using gradle

Tags: windows, gradle

I need to run a .exe file which is in specific location.

This is the code I'm used

```
tasks.register( 'buildComponents', Exec )
{ 
 dependsOn createSetupIni
 doLast
 {
  exec 
   { 
       workingDir = file('tools/configBuild')
       executable = 'ConfigBuilder.exe'
       args = [ "${configLocation}/setup.ini", "${logFilePath}/configBuild"]      
   }
 }
}
```

But I'm getting below error during the execution.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ConfigBuilder.exe''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:232)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:209)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:356)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'ConfigBuilder.exe'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:97)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:70)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ConfigBuilder.exe" (in directory "<full path>\tools\configBuild"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    ... 9 more
```

Any Idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Sloved it by  removing exec {} block.